# window.open(url,'_blank') opens in background tab, not getting focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

In Chromium-based browsers version 107 I notice opening a new tab with window.open does not give focus to the new tab. Previous it did, and in Firefox it still does

```
//code before
{
  let url = "https://google.com";
  window.open(url,"_blank");
}
```

When I run the window open in the console it does give the tab focus.
Also giving a `return true` or adding `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` before doe not work.

However, if I move the test code to the top of the code block, it does work.

Is Anyone aware of a change in Chromium, or a constraint that will open the new page in the background?

Comment: Does not happen to me.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it will automatically open a new page in the background.
Unfortunately, there is no way around this.

Sorry :(

Answer (score -1):

My Chrome is 107.0.5304.107.
Doing this will create a new tab and give it focus.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    let url = "https://google.com";
    window.open(url, "_blank");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please post your html and JavaScript.